# What is considered a large sql table considering number of fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I know the question does not make that good of a sense.

- What is a typical number of columns in a small, medium and large table (in a database) in professional environment.

Want to get an idea what is a good design, how big I can grow my table column wise. Is 100 columns or 200 columns in a table OK?

Comment: What is considered a small, medium, and large number of people in a group?   (answer: it depends!)

Comment: for a party 10 is small, 20 is medium,30 is crowd :) I am asking in a professional environment.

Comment: It depends...once we had 115 fields on normalized environment.

Comment: @knvn that is the type of answer I am looking for.

Comment: My current project has a total of 582 tables with between 1 and 168 **columns**

Comment: My largest table has 102 columns and considering it to grow a little bit.

Comment: A significant aspect not mentioned is the size of individual columns.  Some columns may be a single bit, others may be megabytes.

Answer (score 4):

It totally depends upon the nature of the subject you are modeling. If you need one column, you need one; if you need 500, then you need 500. Properly designed, the size of the tables you end up with will always be "just right".

How big can they be, what performs well, what if you need more columns than you can physically stuff into SQL... those are all implementation, maintenance, and/or performance questions, and that's a different and *secondary* subject. Get the models right first, then worry about implementation.

Comment: So in my case the data is essentially in one table and there is no dependency on others, that means I can just grow my table column wise to accommodate more changes. There is no such thing as oh! 300 column!, that is bad!

Comment: Everyone's a critic. I see a 100+ column table, my first reaction is probably going to be "they obviously didn't know what they were doing". My immediate second take (these days, after years of experience aka learning I got it wrong more often than I'll readily admit) is "but hey, I don't know what they were doing, I'll find out more information before I say that out loud."

Answer (score 3):

Well, for SQL Server 2005, according to the [Max Capacity Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), the maximum number of columns per base table are 1024. So that's a hard upper limit.

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize your tables to at least third normal form ([3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)). That should be your primary guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the row size. 100 sparse columns is differnt from 100 varchar (3000) columns. It is almost always better to make a related table (with an enforced 1-1 relationship) when you are starting to get past the record size that SQL Server can store on one page.

You also should consider how the data will be queried. Are many of those fields ones that will not frequently need to be returned? Do they have a natural grouping (think a person record vice a user login record) and will that natural grouping dictate how they will be queried? In that case it might be better to separate them out.

And of course you should consider normalization. If you are doing multiple columns to avoid having a one-to-many relationship and a join, then you should not do that even if you only have 6 columns.  Joins (with the key fields indexed) are preferable to denormalized tables except in data warehousing situations in general. It is better if you don't have to add new columns because you need to store a new phone type.